# Removing words and symbols from text in R

Tags: r, text, stringr, tm

Consider the following example. Is that possible to delete `stopwords` from `text`?

```
library(tm)
text <- c("this is exercise for text mining ≤µm ≥°f ±μgm")
stopwords <- ("≤µm", "≥°f", "±μgm")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have some errors in your example strings. `text` is missing quotation marks and `stopwords` is missing the `c` before the brackets.

```
text <- c("this is exercise for text mining ≤µm ≥°f ±μgm")
stopwords <- c("≤µm", "≥°f", "±μgm")
```

You can remove the values in stopwords from your string using stringr as below:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(text, paste(stopwords, collapse = "|"), "")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `gsub` like below

```
gsub(paste0(stopwords, collapse = "|"),"",text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are going to be doing text mining, you may be wanting to convert your input string into a vector of words. If so, you can easily remove the stopwords by subsetting.

```
library(stringr)
text <- c("this is exercise for text mining ≤µm ≥°f ±μgm")
stopwords <- c("≤µm", "≥°f", "±μgm")
text <- unlist(str_split(text, " "))
text[!(sapply(text, function (x) any(str_detect(stopwords, x))))]
```

If your work has you putting your words in a data.frame or similar, then there is another way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
text <- c("this is exercise for text mining ≤µm ≥°f ±μgm")
stopwords <- c("≤µm", "≥°f", "±μgm")
text <- unlist(str_split(text, " "))
data.frame(words = text) %>% anti_join(data.frame(words = stopwords))
```